# Search MS Access and display in textboxes VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Please assist. I wish to search the ID number from MS Access table. 
If that ID number exists, I must display the firstname, surname, gender and DOB of the person that has `ID = TextBox.Text`, as follows:

```
Patient_FirstName - txbFirstName
Patient_Surname - txbSurname
Patient_Sex - txbGender
Patient_DOB -txbDOB
```

This data is all contained in a table called `Patient`.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\Siyabonga Kubeka\Documents\Academic Folder\Richfield Graduate Institute Of Technology\BSC GUIDES\BSC GUIDES\Semester 2\Programming 512 Tasks\HealthServiceSystem.accdb"
    conn.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    conn.Open()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Patient where ID like '%" & txbIdNumber.Text & "%'", conn)
    da.Fill(dt)

    txbFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Patient.Patient_First_Name")
    txbSurname.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Patient.Patient_Surname")
    txbDOB.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Patient.Patient_DOB")
    txbGender.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Patient.Patient_Sex")
End Sub
```

I get this error but I cannot figure it out why:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Comment: Uhm, What's the problem? you are not telling us anything.

Please avoid asking qestion on SO if you have not even read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I get this error : System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I'm going to delete my downvote.

Comment: Did you tried: `"Select * from Patient where ID = " & convert.ToInt16(txbIdNumber.Text), conn `

Comment: What is the data type in the database of ID?

Comment: Is ID the primary key of the Patient table?

Comment: The data type is string (text). Yes, ID is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I did get is right, see code below:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\Siyabonga Kubeka\Documents\Academic Folder\Richfield Graduate Institute Of Technology\BSC GUIDES\BSC GUIDES\Semester 2\Programming 512 Tasks\HealthServiceSystem.accdb"
    Dim strSql As String = "Select * from Patient where Patient_ID=@PatientID"
    conn.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    conn.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientID", txbIdNumber.Text)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            txbFirstName.Text += reader("Patient_First_Name").ToString()
            txbSurname.Text += reader("Patient_Surname").ToString()
            txbDOB.Text += reader("Patient_DOB").ToString()
            txbGender.Text += reader("Patient_Sex").ToString()
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```